# How to write a program for input and output redirection wc < f1.txt > f2.txt in c

Tags: c, linux, terminal, operating-system, exec

I was trying something like this but got stuck and don't know in which direction to proceed. I even tried using fork() and then assigning the task separately to child and parent but the redirection in that case in not working as intended.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
int main()
{
    execlp("cat","<","f1.txt",">","f2.txt",NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: may i ask why you're using C if you're doing what is essentially bash? also i think what you're looking for is `fprintf()` and some way to read files. i am sorry, i am not very familar with C. but if `cat < f1.txt > f2.txt` (or `cat f1.txt > f2.txt`) is all you're after, consider bash scripting if that would work for you

Comment: Major reason for using C is that I wanted to implement redirection "<and >" in C by some function like execlp or something else.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux and other POSIXy operating systems, standard input corresponds to file descriptor 0 (`STDIN_FILENO`), standard output to file descriptor 1 (`STDOUT_FILENO`), and standard error to file descriptor 2 (`STDERR_FILENO`).

Standard file handles `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are the standard C abstraction, and in Linux are implemented on top of those file descriptors.

To redirect standard input, output, or error, first you need to get an open file descriptor to whatever you want to redirect from/to.  In the case of files, you do this via the [`open()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) function, which returns the file descriptor number.  Then, you use the [`dup2()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html) function to duplicate (copy) that to the descriptor you want.

Consider the following `example.c`:

```c
// SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* Duplicate oldfd to newfd, and close oldfd.
   In error cases, tries to close both descriptors.
   Returns 0 if success, error code (with errno set) otherwise.
*/
static inline int move_descriptor(int oldfd, int newfd)
{
    if (oldfd == -1 || newfd == -1) {
        if (oldfd != -1)
            close(oldfd);
        if (newfd != -1)
            close(newfd);
        return errno = EBADF;
    }

    if (oldfd == newfd)
        return 0;

    if (dup2(oldfd, newfd) == -1) {
        const int  saved_errno = errno;
        close(oldfd);
        close(newfd);
        return errno = saved_errno;
    }

    if (close(oldfd) == -1) {
        const int  saved_errno = errno;
        close(newfd);
        return errno = saved_errno;
    }

    return 0;
}


/* Write a message to standard error, keeping errno unchanged.
   This is async-signal safe.
   Returns 0 if success, error code otherwise.
*/
static inline int wrerr(const char *msg)
{
    const char *end = (msg) ? msg + strlen(msg) : msg;

    if (end == msg)
        return 0;

    const int  saved_errno = errno;

    while (msg < end) {
        ssize_t  n = write(STDERR_FILENO, msg, (size_t)(end - msg));
        if (n > 0) {
            msg += n;
        } else
        if (n != -1) {
            errno = saved_errno;
            return EIO;
        } else
        if (errno != EINTR) {
            const int  retval = errno;
            errno = saved_errno;
            return retval;
        }
    }

    errno = saved_errno;
    return 0;
}

static inline void errormessage(const char *name, const char *cause)
{
    wrerr(name);
    wrerr(": ");
    wrerr(cause);
    wrerr(".\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int  fd;

    if (argc < 4 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        const char *arg0 = (argc > 0 && argv && argv[0] && argv[0][0]) ? argv[0] : "(this)";
        wrerr("\n");
        wrerr("Usage: "); wrerr(arg0); wrerr(" [ -h | --help ]\n");
        wrerr("       "); wrerr(arg0); wrerr(" INPUT OUTPUT COMMAND [ ARGUMENTS ... ]\n");
        wrerr("\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        errormessage(argv[1], strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (move_descriptor(fd, STDIN_FILENO)) {
        errormessage(argv[1], strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fd = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666);
    if (fd == -1) {
        errormessage(argv[2], strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (move_descriptor(fd, STDOUT_FILENO)) {
        errormessage(argv[2], strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (strchr(argv[3], '/'))
        execv(argv[3], (char *const *)(argv + 3));
    else
        execvp(argv[3], (char *const *)(argv + 3));

    errormessage(argv[3], strerror(errno));
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

The `move_descriptor()` is just a wrapper around `dup2()` and `close()`.  I included it to show how to do the descriptor moving (copying and closing the old one) *safely*; with sufficient error checking.

The `wrerr(msg)` function is analogous to `fputs(msg, stderr)`, except that it uses the file descriptor interface ([`write()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)) directly, bypassing the C stderr stream abstraction completely.  It is also [async-signal safe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)<sup>*</sup>, meaning you can use it inside signal handlers.

<sup>*</sup>: Technically, one could argue whether `strlen()` is async-signal safe or not.  In Linux using glibc, newlibc, or avr-libc, it is.

Many Linux/Unix/POSIXy error messages use format *"filename: Error message."* Since the `wrerr()` function takes only one parameter, I included the `errormessage(filename, message)` helper function to print such error messages.  This kind of splitting commonly used tasks to helper functions makes the code easier to read, and easier to maintain too.

The program itself takes at least four command-line arguments.  (The first argument, `argv[0]`, is the command itself.  The first *parameter* is `argv[1]`. For example, if you compile and ran this as `./example arg1 arg2 arg3`, then `argv[0]=="./example"`, `argv[1]=="arg1"`, `argv[2]=="arg2"`, and `argv[3]=="arg3"`.  In Linux and POSIXy systems, `argv[argc] == NULL`, so we can use the `argv` array directly in [`execv()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execv.3.html) and [`execvp()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html) and related functions.

If there are fewer than four command-line parameters, or if `argv[1]` matches `"-h"` or `"--h"`, we print *usage* and exit.

Otherwise, the first parameter (`argv[1]`) names the file we redirect input from (and it must exist), and the second parameter (`argv[2]`) the file we redirect output to (which we'll create if it does not exist yet).

The `O_NOCTTY` flag may look confusing at first, but I included it, because it is so common when redirecting input from file-like objects.  It basically means that even if the pathname refers to a terminal, don't do any terminal and session related magic when opening it: *"if it is a terminal, and we don't happen to have a controlling terminal, don't make it our controlling terminal"*.  (It only affects programs run in a new session (via [`setsid`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setsid.1.html)) or by services like cron, udev, et cetera, since programs you normally run from a terminal have that terminal as their controlling terminal.  The main thing about terminals and sessions is that if the controlling terminal gets closed, each process having that terminal as their controlling terminal will receive a hangup (`SIGHUP`) signal.)

When opening the file we redirect output to, we use `O_CREAT` flag, and add an extra parameter, the *file access mode*.  The leading zero means that `0666` is an octal constant, i.e. base-8, and refers to decimal value 6·8<sup>2</sup> + 6·8<sup>1</sup> + 6·8<sup>0</sup> = 438.  It is the standard value that you see most often used.  It is modified (by the kernel) by the current umask (whose value you can see in the shell by running `umask`).  It is written in octal because then the third digit from right specifies the owner (user) rights, second from right the group rights, and the rightmost the rights for everyone else; `1` being read access, `2` being write access, and `4` being execute (for files) or pass through/work in (for directories).  (Each file has an owner (user) and group in Linux, as they do in all Unix and POSIXy systems.)

Whenever `open()` flags include `O_CREAT`, the additional access mode value must be supplied.  It will almost always be `0666`, except for some rare cases where you want to use a more restrictive value; but the general rule is to use `0666` and let the user make it more restrictive if they want by modifying their `umask`: that is what just about all utilities do anyway.

The third command line parameter (fourth argument, `argv[3]`), contains the name or path to the executable we'll run.  If it contains a slash (`/`), we assume it is a pathname reference, and use `execv()`.  If it does not contain a slash, we assume it is a name, and use `execvp()`, which uses the `PATH` environment variable to look for an executable with that name.

If the exec succeeds, the process is replaced with the new program; the execution ends at the exec.

If the exec fails for any reason, both execv() and execvp() will set errno.  It makes sense to print the command (without any arguments, if there were any), and the error message, and exit with failure in that case.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, redirection is a shell feature.

I don't see what you are trying to do. But to achieve what you are trying, you need to run

```
sh -c 'cat < f1.txt > f2.txt'
```

in the exec format. (I am not familiar with the exec format in C)

You can use `bash` instead of `sh`. The `-c` flag takes a string argument — called command string, and executes it.

---

My **guess** of the exec format would be:

```
execlp( "sh", "-c", " 'cat < f1.txt > f2.txt' ", NULL);
```

Note the third argument to the function is enclosed in two sets of quotes `" '...' "`. This is a requirement. Else the shell's space splitting will break it and pass only `cat` as the command string.